# Symmetry group for (noncommutative) manifold from spectral triple

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, noncommutative-geometry

(This post is cross-post in Mathematics Stack Exchanges https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3992766/symmetry-group-for-noncommutative-manifold)

Is there any notion of symmetry group arise for spectral triple $(A,H,D)$? I can't find any reference about that. Even in the case of commutative $A$, can we reconstruct the isometry group of the corresponding Riemannian manifold from spectral triple?

Comment: I am very far from being an expert on this kind of NCG, but I think there have been papers by Bhowmick, Goswami and various coauthors on this kind of theme. Perhaps searching under those names might lead to things which are what you are after? (Apologies if you've already looked at this and it's not what you are after.)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have looked into works of Goswami, and I am not exactly sure if it is what I thought of. I will try to read those papers then

Comment: The work of Bhowmick and Goswami on quantum isometry groups of spectral triples is exactly what you want; indeed, they even wrote a monograph on the subject, *Quantum Isometry Groups*.

Comment: As for the commutative case, Goswami has proved [(in a paper recently published in Advances)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.05765) that if $Q$ is a compact quantum group coacting faithfully on the Fréchet pre-C*-algebra $C^\infty(M)$ for $M$ a compact connected manifold, then $Q = C(G)$ for $G$ a compact Lie group and the coaction of $Q$ is induced by a Lie action of $G$ on $M$; in other words, a compact connected manifold admits no truly quantum symmetries.

Comment: That said, there is a little bit of wriggle room for a “quantum permutation group” to coact on $C^\infty(M)$ (and hence on a commutative spectral triple for $M$) if $M$ is disconnected.